# Springboot custom Select Query returns No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to execute a custom select query in Springboot JPA,

```
public interface idnOauth2AccessTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<idnOauth2AccessToken, String>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<idnOauth2AccessToken> {
    @Query(value = "select IOCA.userName, IOCA.appName, IOAT.refreshToken, IOAT.timeCreated, IOAT.tokenScopeHash, IOAT.tokenState, IOAT.validityPeriod from idnOauth2AccessToken IOAT inner join idnOauthConsumerApps IOCA on IOCA.ID = IOAT.consumerKeyID where IOAT.tokenState='ACTIVE'")
    List<userApplicationModel> getUserApplicationModel();
}
```

But when I execute I get an error of

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.adl.egw.Model.user.userApplicationModel]
```

I tried different type of answers from the internet, but I nothing seems to work fine. I also tried implementing a new repository for userApplicationModel but didn't work.

Any answers or implementation which could help.

Comment: Could you make a try with `UserApplicationModel` instead of `userApplicationModel`?

Comment: @GaborSzabo This didn't help, I even tried renaming  the class too.

Comment: Can you check with the answer given in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194243/how-to-resolve-no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-tuplebackedmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining columns from different tables and then assigning to a different object. It does not work this way + the `userApplicationModel` doesn't seem managed entity. For such scenarios, you have to use projection(dto mapping). Take a look of the following `Query`:

```
@Query(value = "select new your.package.UserApplicationModelProjection(IOCA.userName, IOCA.appName, IOAT.refreshToken, IOAT.timeCreated, IOAT.tokenScopeHash, IOAT.tokenState, IOAT.validityPeriod)" 
             + " from idnOauth2AccessToken IOAT inner join idnOauthConsumerApps IOCA on IOCA.ID = IOAT.consumerKeyID where IOAT.tokenState='ACTIVE'")
List<UserApplicationModelProjection> getUserApplicationModel();
```

And the class to map to:

```
public class UserApplicationModelProjection {
    private String userName;
    private String appName;
    private String refreshToken
    private OffsetDateTime timeCreated
    private String tokenScopeHash;
    private String tokenState; //mind the data type
    private int validityPeriod; //update the data type
    
    public UserApplicationModelProjection(String userName, 
                                        String appName, 
                                        String refreshToken, 
                                        OffsetDateTime timeCreated, 
                                        String tokenScopeHash, 
                                        String tokenState, 
                                        int validityPeriod) 
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.appName = appName; 
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
        this.tokenScopeHash = tokenScopeHash; 
        this.tokenState = tokenState;
        this.validityPeriod = validityPeriod;
    }
    
    // Getters only
    
}
```

Check this for detailed explanation: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/